# row_number over multiple columns based on trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to factor in multiple conditions to a dataset I'm working with.  Row_number seems like the way to go with lag function in a second query but I can't quite get it 100%.

Here is how my data is structured:

```
CREATE TABLE emailhell(
   mainID  INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,acctID  VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
  ,emailID VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
  ,type    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,created DATETIME  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (1,'1234','1',6,'1/1/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (2,'1234','1',11,'1/1/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (3,'1234','2',6,'1/2/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (4,'1234','3',6,'1/3/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (5,'1234','4',6,'1/4/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (6,'ABC','89',6,'1/5/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (7,'ABC','90',6,'1/6/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (8,'ABC','90',11,'1/7/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (9,'258','22',6,'1/7/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (10,'258','1',6,'1/10/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (11,'258','2',6,'1/30/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (12,'258','3',6,'1/31/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (13,'258','29',6,'2/15/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (14,'258','29',11,'2/16/2018');
INSERT INTO emailhell(mainID,acctID,emailID,type,created) VALUES (15,'258','31',6,'3/1/2018');
```

and my desired output

```
   +--------+--------+---------+------+-----------+-------+------------+
| mainID | acctID | emailID | type |  created  | index | touchcount |
+--------+--------+---------+------+-----------+-------+------------+
|      1 | 1234   |       1 |    6 | 1/1/2018  |     1 |            |
|      2 | 1234   |       1 |   11 | 1/1/2018  |     2 |          1 |
|      3 | 1234   |       2 |    6 | 1/2/2018  |     1 |            |
|      4 | 1234   |       3 |    6 | 1/3/2018  |     2 |            |
|      5 | 1234   |       4 |    6 | 1/4/2018  |     3 |            |
|      6 | ABC    |      89 |    6 | 1/5/2018  |     1 |            |
|      7 | ABC    |      90 |    6 | 1/6/2018  |     2 |            |
|      8 | ABC    |      90 |   11 | 1/7/2018  |     3 |          2 |
|      9 | 258    |      22 |    6 | 1/7/2018  |     1 |            |
|     10 | 258    |       1 |    6 | 1/10/2018 |     2 |            |
|     11 | 258    |       2 |    6 | 1/30/2018 |     3 |            |
|     12 | 258    |       3 |    6 | 1/31/2018 |     4 |            |
|     13 | 258    |      29 |    6 | 2/15/2018 |     5 |            |
|     14 | 258    |      29 |   11 | 2/16/2018 |     6 |          5 |
|     15 | 258    |      31 |    6 | 3/1/2018  |     1 |            |
+--------+--------+---------+------+-----------+-------+------------+
```

Here's what I was working with but It's having issues for some reason when the activity looks like, Type 6 followed by an 11 followed by a 6, 11, etc.  Here's my start of the query and I'm sure there's a better way to do this.  I am then doing a similar query with the LAG function to grab the times where type 11 appeared.

```
SELECT dm.TABLE.*, 
       row_number() over(partition by dm.acctId, dm.type order by dm.acctId, dm.created_date) as index into dm.table2 
from dm.TABLE with (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: So you want to Count the number of records that have a type value of 6?

Comment: `NOLOCK` means `return dirty data while taking more locks`. It's *not* a go-fast hint. If you think you need it, it means you have a performance issue

Comment: I want to count the number of preceding 6's when an 11 shows up by for each acctId, and emailId.  

NOLOCK is out of habit from pulling data from production datastores.  I'm not worried about the NOLOCK or dirty data since I'm the only user of the table.  The query finishes in a matter of seconds, I'm not having a performance issue.

Comment: NOLOCK means you are ok with your results being mostly accurate most of the time. You can and will get duplicate and/or missing rows. Unless you really understand that hint you should avoid it. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: IF Im reading your example data correctly, it looks like you don't care about the emailId as you have 5 as the total count for acctId 258 up until it hits 11 but the emailId is different

Comment: @Kyle NOLOCK *should never be used on production databases*. Not only are you pulling *dirty* data, you are *increasing blocking for everyone else*. In any case, you *haven't* explained what you want, only how you think it can be produced.

Comment: @SeanLange This is a question, but I read that giving the engine a NOLOCK, OR ROWLOCK hint does not necessarily mean the engine will abide by that. It's more of a suggestion. Is that correct?

Comment: What we really need here is some details. The table structure, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @RyanWilson no that isn't correct. Read the article I posted about NOLOCK.

Comment: +1 to sample data and examples of the desired output. The screenshot doesn't help. It can't be converted to a query for experimenting either

Comment: @SeanLange Ok. Thanks Sean.

Comment: @Kyle is type 11 the *end marker of a range?* Do you want to rank account rows of type 6 in the regions delimited by 11?

Comment: Ok, let me work on getting this into SQL Fiddle or something and I'll re-do my question above.  Hang tight and thanks for all responses already, I appreciate it!

Comment: @panagiotis kanavos

Basically it's a table of emails.  a type 6 denotes, an email was SENT.  an 11 means that an email was READ.  When an email is read, it wil have the same emailId as one that was sent for that particular customer/account.  What I'm trying to do is say, how many times do we send an email to a customer BEFORE they open one.  So, it's entirely plausible that we sent out 1000 emails and there is never a type 11 record. or, they could open every single email.  That's why I want/need to reset the counter at every 11.  Working on some better details for above right now.

Comment: @Kyle update the *question*. That's a clear description of the problem. The image and query are definitely *not*. This is a variation of the `islands` problem.

Comment: Question is already updated.  @SeanLange thanks for those links, was a huge help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining groups by `acctId` and `11`.  Then for the `11`s, you want one less than the size of the group.  So, cumulative sum and some other stuff:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by acctId, grp order by mainId) as index,
       (case when type = 11
             then count(*) over (partition by acctId, grp ) - 1
        end) as touchcount
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when type = 11 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by acctId order by mainId desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

I should note that the definition of group requires counting backwards, rather than forwards.  That is because `11` is included in the "previous" group rather than the first record in the "next" group.

Comment: A few typos, eg should be `[index]` instead of just `index` and the `touchcount` expression should be `count(*)  over (partition by acctId, grp) - 1`

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Looking at this, logically it makes sense.  I honestly didn't know SQL could get this powerful(SaS./R guy).

The one thing I can't figure out; if I can run the second half individually to establish the "grp" it works fine.  However, when I try and run the entire block, it seems as if it doesn't like the initial t.* and the t; at the end.  At least there's where the red underlines are.

Could this be a version issue?

Comment: Nevermind, figure it out.  Syntax issue with aliases..This is awesome and I thank everyone for their help!